# Variation diminishing property

Tags: geometry, numerical-methods, curves, bezier-curve

in the book "CAGD" by Farin he gives a proof of the variation diminishing property for piecewise linear interpolation. Given a continuous curve $c$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ we define a piecewise linear interpolant of the curve $\mathcal{PL}\,c$ as a polygon (sequence of straight line segments joining points $\mathbb{b}_i,\mathbb{b}_{i+1}$ whose vertices lie on the curve. The variation diminishing property states that, given an arbitrary plane, the number of intersections of the plane with the curve is less or equal to the number of intersections of the plane with the piecewise linear interpolant.

I don't get what happens when the plane contains one of the straight line segments of $\mathcal{PL}\,c$. How precisely is the defined this "number of intersections"?

Comment: Your doubt is justified, if you read "arbitrary" as "any". The statement would be correct if "arbitrary" has the flavor of "generic", "in general position".

Comment: I don't understand what "general position" is and wherever i find statements for the variation diminishing property they talk about any line or plane.  I found on wikipedia the concept of "general position" as something similar to linearly independent vectors but for points. How is it related to where the plane is? Can i restate the property as any plane that doesn't contain any straight line segment?

Comment: There is a thin set of planes with special properties related to the given geometric situation, like having more than one node point inside. The remaining dense set is in general position.

Comment: How can i formalize the concept of density and measure zero in the context of planes in $\mathbb{R}^3$ ? I changed the property to be valid for any plane except a finite number.

Comment: "Finite" will not work, there are infinitely many planes containing a given line or line segment. But that set has co-dimension 2 in the set of all planes, so has measure zero in some suitable parametrization of the space of planes.

Comment: If i consider the space of planes like an affine grassmannian and parametrize it with $\mathbb{PR}^2\times\mathbb{R}^3$ with $([a],b) \to a\cdot v+b=0$, how can i prove that that subset of planes has measure zero? Is it enought to prove that fixed a line $P+x \in \mathbb{R}^3$,  a plane cointaining that line has equation $a \cdot v+P=0$ where $a \in Span(x)^{\perp}$ and these $([a],P)$ have measure zero (which measure?)? If yes why?

Comment: I was arguing that differentiable sub-manifolds of positive co-dimension have always measure zero in a topology-compatible measure (Borel, Lebesgue).